# Passing a function to jquery text() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this code:

`$('li').text(
    function(i, text){
        return (i+1)+ ". " + text;
    });`

I'm getting numbers for list items in order starting from 1 to the last list item, and it works nicely. But when I use i++ insted of i+1, numbers start from 0. So insted 1. for list item 1 I got 0 and so on. What's the catch?

Comment: keeping `i+1` would be good though, as you are not actually incrementing the value. There's a difference between incrementing and using it plus 1.

Comment: it always starts with 0. first element is element #0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use `++i`, `i++` is the post increment operator. You need a pre increment because you want to use the incremented value in the current operation

Comment: I rememebr hearing Douglas Crockford defend this rule in JSLint that prevents the ++ operator because people misunderstand how it works. Seemed a bit strict but I can see how it can trip people up.